# Regular expression: take string literally with special re-characters

Tags: c#, regex

Maybe simple question..

```
String text = "fake 43 60 fake";
String patt = "[43.60]";

Match m = Regex.Match(text, patt)
```

In this situation, m.Success = true because the dot replace any character (also the space). But I must match the string literally in the patt.

Of course, I can use the '\' before the dot in the patt

```
String patt = @"[43\.60]";
```

So the m.Success = false, but there's more special characters in the Regular Expression-world.

My question is, how can I use regular expression that a string will be literally taken as it set. So '43.60' must be match with exactly '43.60'. '43?60' must be match with '43?60'....

thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get a regex-safe literal:

```
string escaped = Regex.Escape(input);
```

For example, to match the *literal* `[43.60]`:

```
string escaped = Regex.Escape(@"[43.60]");
```

gives the string with content: `\[43\.60]`.

You can then use this *escaped* content to create a regex; for example:

```
string find = "43?60";
string escaped = Regex.Escape(find);
bool match = Regex.IsMatch("abc 43?60", escaped);
```

Note that in many cases you will want to *combine* the escaped string with some other regex fragment to make a complete pattern.